# HTML - Select tag - to seatch by string and not number

Tags: html, select, search

I have an inssue with searching of an item in a list while the list is combined with numbers and strings while numbers are at the start.

for example. **I have a list of a type code - value:**

```
[{code: 1111, value: oneoneone}
{code: 2222, value: twotwotwo}
{code: 3333, value: threethree}
{code: 4444, value: fourfourfour}]
```

List looks like this:

```
1111 - oneoneone
2222 - twotwotwo
3333 - threethree
```

code example:

```
<select> class="myClass"
 name="codeValueList"
 [(ngModel)]="selectedItem"
 (ngModelChange)="updateOnProcess($event)"
 <option> [ngValue]="null"></option>
 <option> *ngFor="let item of codeValueList" [ngValue]="s">{s.code + s.value}</option>
```

now while list might be really long I would like to search name by keyboard,
however since numbers start first It only searches by numbers.

is there a way to ignore search by number and only search by string using selected tag?

I tried using dataList however it doesnt work properly with an object of code value.

thanks

Comment: "*I would like to search name by keyboard, however since numbers start first It only searches by numbers*" - you'd need to share your search functionality, and while you're using Angular (I assume), what we'd need to see is a sample of the generated list, rather than the Angular script that generates that list.

Comment: @DavidThomas is there a way to use a filter function? I didnt even know that. I can do it but where do I implement the call on template? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can use JavaScript, here is an example filter using Html, CSS and JavaScript

HTLM:

```
<!-- Control buttons -->
<div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('cars')"> Cars</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('animals')"> Animals</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('fruits')"> Fruits</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('colors')"> Colors</button>
</div>

    <!-- The filterable elements. Note that some have multiple class names (this can be used if they belong to multiple categories) -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="filterDiv cars">BMW</div>
      <div class="filterDiv colors fruits">Orange</div>
      <div class="filterDiv cars">Volvo</div>
      <div class="filterDiv colors">Red</div>
      <div class="filterDiv cars">Ford</div>
      <div class="filterDiv colors">Blue</div>
      <div class="filterDiv animals">Cat</div>
      <div class="filterDiv animals">Dog</div>
      <div class="filterDiv fruits">Melon</div>
      <div class="filterDiv fruits animals">Kiwi</div>
      <div class="filterDiv fruits">Banana</div>
      <div class="filterDiv fruits">Lemon</div>
      <div class="filterDiv animals">Cow</div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.filterDiv {
  float: left;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px;
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
}

/* The "show" class is added to the filtered elements */
.show {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Add a light grey background on mouse-over */
.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Add a dark background to the active button */
.btn.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
filterSelection("all")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  // Add the "show" class (display:block) to the filtered elements, and remove the "show" class from the elements that are not selected
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

// Show filtered elements
function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
      element.className += " " + arr2[i];
    }
  }
}

// Hide elements that are not selected
function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}

// Add active class to the current control button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```